# Game area where I can not click?

Tags: unreal-4, blueprints

I created a project based on the Top Down Example.

What is happening is that there is an area just above my character where I can not click.

**Image showing location where the mouse is and soon after, when I move it a little to the left it disappears:**

[image]

By the minimap you can see that the game recognizes as if the mouse was on top of the character, very close.

**I went to test to see if this happened in all Top Down Examples, but it does not happen:**

[image]

I've modified the position of the camera a bit in this project where I'm having problems (**image 1**). Is there a non-clickable area defined based on the camera, to prevent the player from clicking the location where the character is? And with the change of position the area is no longer equivalent to the position of the character?

**This area in red I can not click:**

[image]

**I have not changed anything that has to do with the mouse in the character's blueprint:**

[image]

What is going on?

---

**EDIT 1 (tests done based on some comments to clarify the question and to verify possible cause of the problem)**

**I pressed P to see if there was any area of ​​the map where there could be no click:**

[image]

**See I can put my mouse right below the character, and even click:**

[image]

**From there up the mouse does not appear, and obviously I can not click:**

[image]

**Location where the mouse appears again and what I can click:**

[image]

These 3 images were captured in the character's home position without moving it. But the problem persists wherever the character is.

**Through the test I did below, I prove that the problem is directly related to the position the character is in:**

[image]

The green question marks the spot where my mouse is.

---

**EDIT 2 (I think I discovered the problem)**

I read DMGregory's comment again and went to look at the collider, it was small and it already existed before the problem happened.

**I started the game and paused. I came across this image:**

[image]

I created this sprite to appear on the minimap, I believe that may be the cause of the problem. How to make the mouse skip it? Without having to simply upload it?

Comment: Is it possible you're hitting the character's collider, instead of the ground plane, due to either your click raycast or the collider itself being offset from where you expect them to be?

Comment: I presume you're using a NavMeshBoundsVolume for AI movement.  In the editor, in the Viewport window, go to Show and tick Navigation.  If where you cannot click is green then it's not a NavMesh issue and is likely to be you hitting something else as DMGregory says.  If it's a red area then try deleting and replacing.

Comment: I dont get the question, does happen when you click on minimap ? On character? Somewhere in viewport?

Comment: Also I would encourage you to log what you hit. And the Worldlocation of the hit - it will give you a lot of information.

Comment: @ColdSteel The problem happens when I try to make the character walk in the game. Giving a simple click. In this place the decals does not appear, only on the minimap.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I put in the second edition of the question, the mouse click was not working as it ended up being blocked by the sprite.

**I did not know what was happening because I selected the option where the owner did not see the sprite (the sprite is only useful for the minimap):**

[image]

Only thing I did was climb the sprite to the point where it is not seen by the camera that follows the character.